# Python try except fail to catch RemoteDataError

Tags: python, try-catch, yahoo-finance, except

I am using the following code to read data from yahoo finance from a list symbols downloaded from nasdaq.

```
pnls = {i:dreader.DataReader(i,'yahoo','1985-01-01','2017-03-30') for i in symbols}

for df_name in pnls:
    try: 
        pnls.get(df_name).to_csv("/Users/Jiong/Documents/data/{}_data.csv".format(df_name), index=True, header=True)
    except: 
        print("error {}".format(df_name))
    else: 
        print("done {}".format(df_name))
```

Guess some symbols may not be valid and Yahoo Finance throws `RemoteDataError Exception`.

The code above is supposed to continue on, but it stopped still at the errors.

Isn't except to catch all exceptions? or this is run time error ?

Anyway to get the code ignores it and continue? Thanks. See errors below running

```
118         if params is not None and len(params) > 0:
119             url = url + "?" + urlencode(params)
--> 120         raise RemoteDataError('Unable to read URL: {0}'.format(url))
121 
122     def _read_lines(self, out):
```

---

```
RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?c=1985&f=2017&s=MITT%5EA&g=d&ignore=.csv&d=2&e=30&a=0&b=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the raise exception or it will halt at the place of raised. So, if a raise exception is not caught and handled, it will be interrupted.

What you need is something like this :

```
except RemoteDataError as exp : 
    print('Unable to read URL: {0}'.format(url))
```

You can refer to [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) for more details on errors.

Comment: Thank you! It still raises the error. I read exceet without exception name will catch all exceptions.

Comment: Yes, but it not a good practice to suppress all all exceptions. First identify the correct name by removing the `try-catch` block and only put the names that are necessary inside except.

Comment: Any idea why it still stops even the exception is handled? Is this due to it was a runtime error?

Comment: Runtimes are handled through that. Check if the error name is correct by removing the try-except block.

Comment: If I used the catch all syntax, is't it suppose to continue?

Comment: These are a few symbols that throws the routine off. dd=dd[~dd['Symbol'].str.contains('BGX|CBO|NTEST|JCO|SCQ|APHB|IBO|ATEST') ]. Also, Python seems did not return any results if there is any exception on these symbols(unless all these symbols were removed). I am using notes, not sure if this is right. Sorry new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

Grabbed this import from another page; it seemed to correct the issue for me. I was getting a remote error while trying to pull stock data from Yahoo. You'll need to do the following import prior to adding the RemoteDataError exception:

```
from pandas_datareader._utils import RemoteDataError

df_ = pd.DataFrame()
for i in assets:
    print(i)
    try:
        vec = web.DataReader(i, 'yahoo', start='12/10/2006', end='2/1/2007')
        vec['asset'] = i
        vec['returns_close_raw'] = np.log(vec.Close/vec.Close.shift())
        vec['returns_open_raw'] = np.log(vec.Open/vec.Open.shift())
        vec['returns_open_raw10'] = np.log(vec.Open/vec.Open.shift(10))
        vec['returns_close_raw10'] = np.log(vec.Close/vec.Close.shift(10))
        df_ = pd.concat([df_, vec])

    except RemoteDataError:
        print('remote error')

    except KeyError:
        print('key error')
```

Comment: Please, try to explain a little bit more what your code does.